# How to keep Kubernetes' deployments' images in sync with Devops Library or variables.tf?

Tags: azure-devops

How to fully automate this all, such that a terraform-coded version of a statefulset that specifies which image (repo/name:tag) to use for the statefulset pods is in sync after upgrades to image tag?

For example, its rather trivial to do the following 3:

1. upon source code change to trigger a terraform CI artifact copy and a following CD release to apply the terraform.  all automatic
2. use variables (variables.tf, ReplaceTokens, Library vars, or some combination of the 3) in the statefulset's .tf files that dictate which $(repo/name:tag) image to use for the pods in a stateful set.  all automatic
3. upon source code change of a Dockerfile to trigger an image build and push to ACR repo.  all automatic

but then you actually want the statefulset's pods to start running the new image.  so you could then us a kubectl patch/delete as a task after the docker push.  but then your .tf source and/or your Library variables are out of sync.  Surely there is a good way to push a Dockerfile change and then expect to have your new pods running shortly after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this approach:

- build CI (build) pipeline to create docker image with tag as commit id
- then CD (release) pipeline to deploy a new version of images with Helm script. You pass there your commit id as a parameter so you are sure that the newest docker image id deployed. Since you have all your yaml file in Helm script you should be still in sync. For commit id you can use `Build.SourceVersion` variable. CD is triggered right after CI is finished.

Is this what you are looking for?